# How to query MongoDB from R?

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb, rmongo

I want to get a MongoDB query from R.

With the `mongo` shell, I would query with:

```
db.user.find({age:{$gt:21}})
```

However, In R-Mongo, I haven't found how to describe this query.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about the rmongodb package - https://github.com/gerald-lindsly/rmongodb?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using rmongodb (there is a similar package called Rmongo):

```
     r <- mongo.find(mongo, "test.user", list(age=list('$gt'=21L)))
```

the BSON query object can also be built like so:

```
     buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create()
     mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(buf, "age")
     mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "$gt", 21L)
     mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf)
     query <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf)
     r <- mongo.find("mongo", "test.user", query)
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using [RMongo](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMongo/index.html), the query would be:

```
 dbGetQuery(mongo, "user","{'age':{'$gt': 21}}}")
```

The result of dbGetQuery() will be a [Data Frame](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame).

Answer (score 1):

I have also written light interface to R of the pymongo package (the official API for python)
https://github.com/RockScience/Rpymongo/blob/master/Rpymongo.r
It mimics as close as possible the functions and arguments on the official page of the API
http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html